# Get latest 5 posts from subcategories of a category with the loop in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I need to get the latest 5 posts from the subcategories of a category.
How do i do this?

//edit
So i got it working for a fixed ammount of posts per subcategory:

```
<?php $descendants = get_categories(array('child_of' => 3)); ?> 
<?php $cnt=1;
foreach ($descendants as $child) { ?>
<?php $catPosts = new WP_Query();
    $catPosts -> query("showposts=3&cat=$child->term_id");
 ?>
<ul class="postPreviews">
<?php while ($catPosts->have_posts()) : $catPosts->the_post(); ?>
<li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
    <div class="descOverlay">
        <img src="<?php the_field('teaserimage'); ?>" />
        <div class="overlayTitle">
            <div class="imgwrap"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/opaq.png"></div>
            <span><?php the_title(); ?></span></div>
        </div>
    </a></li>
<?php endwhile; 
}?>
```

Comment: I think the question is clear enough, even if it's short. In case you really want to help and need more information, let me know.

Comment: let me expand, S.O questions should contain code, should tell us what you tried, where it failed ... (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I didn't try anything, because i can't think of a solution. I tried to find an answer for my question on google, but without success.

Comment: you tried nothing, and had no result? i'm shocked.

Comment: i only kow how to get posts from a single category or from all of them. And i know thats not gonna work for me this time, because that's not what i need.

Comment: If you really want to help, you can look at my code now and maybe suggest a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use get_categories() to loop through all subcategories and add their IDs to an array.  Then you can use that array for the category__in' parameter for a new WP_Query.

```
<?php
    $categories = get_categories( array(
        'child_of'=>'your_category_id'
    ) );

    $subcategories = array();

    foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
        $subcategories[] = $category->cat_ID;
    }
?>

<?php
    $new_loop = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'category__in' => $subcategories,
    'posts_per_page' => 5
    ) );
?>

<?php if ( $new_loop->have_posts() ) : while ( $new_loop->have_posts() ) : $new_loop->the_post(); ?>

    // put your inside the loop code here

<?php endwhile; else: ?>
    No posts found
<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```